# Splitting a string by space to pipe into parallel in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a piece of bash code that loops over filenames that are in a string separated by spaces. This then runs a function against each filename. It looks like so:

```
TCURR=0
for F in $FILES; do
  TCURR=$[TCURR + 1]
  do_something $TCURR $F &
done
wait
```

How can I make this work with gnu parallel? I can't figure out how to pipe the $FILES variable into it so it works.

Here's what I've tried, neither of which work. I based these off the parallel examples page. I'm just sending 1 instead of TCURR as the first variable to the function for simplicity although I would like to know how to do that too.

`$FILES | parallel "do_something 1 {}"`

`echo $FILES | parallel "do_something 1 {}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parallel do_something {#} {} ::: $FILES
```

Comment: Awesome didn't know you could use {#} as a counter.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, just needed quotes around the variable. So it looks like:

`echo "$FILES" | parallel "do_something 1 {}"`

Although I haven't figured out how to make the counter work yet

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=....
TCURR=0
for F in $FILES; do
    ((TCURR++))
    echo do_something $TCURR $F 
done | parallel
```